# Building several .c cython modules into a single .exe

Tags: python, cython

I have an application with a number of .pyx modules (every single module is cythonised) and am looking to compile it to a single standalone .exe.

I've come across a number of instructions that give instructions for a single file, but I'm not quite sure how to translate this to compiling 10 .c modules into one.

Thank you very much for any advice

Comment: Perhaps you could use PyInstaller? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen

Comment: And what is exact your difficulties with multiple modules, how is it different from using just one?

Comment: Despite the link I don't really recommend Cython for this. Things like PyInstaller (or even other compilers like Nuitka) make a much bigger effort to make this work